# formatting bug when using long url

Tags: support, bug, status-declined

When I use a long url, it writes over the advertisement. User name and icon overflows into related items. See:

[WCF support in Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509536/wcf-support-in-mono)

I have now fixed it as per random's comment. But I still think that it is a bug, and the system could wrap it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's why it's a good idea to make the link text contextual and not just dump the URL.

You wouldn't want something like this:

[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/comeoneverybodyletsgetdownanddirtyplayingaroundintheformattingsandboxwhereyoucanputsanddownyoursocksandwalkalldaylonglikeyouareatthebeachbutwithoutthatwetstuffgettinginthewayofmakingyourdayniceandseasidesunshiny)

when you could have something [just tucked away naturally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/comeoneverybodyletsgetdownanddirtyplayingaroundintheformattingsandboxwhereyoucanputsanddownyoursocksandwalkalldaylonglikeyouareatthebeachbutwithoutthatwetstuffgettinginthewayofmakingyourdayniceandseasidesunshiny).

Comment: It's still a bug, though: there's a missing `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:scroll` style somewhere.

Comment: @Joel: they have already said that they won't change it though...